# Does the inequality $1+x \leq e^x, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ hold for complex $x$ as well?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I know $1+x \leq e^x$ for all real $x$. I want to use inequality $\textbf{for complex $x$}$ in a proof I'm doing. Is it true?

Comment: What does it even mean for $x\leq y$ if $x,y$ are complex? In shot, the answer to your question is no (as stated).

Comment: No, inequalities in general do not make sense for complex numbers.

Comment: @Clayton Not meaning to be grammar guy, but \*short\*, not shot.

Comment: @Simply the wonderful world of cell phones lol

Comment: @Clayton I feel you.  I definitely feel you.  Auto-correct is a pain for m.se, especially with all the MathJax/LaTeX stuff.

Answer (score 5):

It is meaningless for complex $x$: the $\le$ relation is not defined for complex numbers.

Comment: My mistake, I'm tired haha. The context my teacher used this in was actually $1 + |f_n(x)| \leq e^{|f_n(x)|}$ where $f_n(x)$ is a $\textbf{complex-valued function}$. However, when you take the absolute value you obviously get a real number.

Comment: @antsatsui I think it will be better if you edit the question directly adding this context.